# Why would *some* Outlook installations not open correctly formed "msg" file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I use Outlook for my personal information manager (PIM), which encompasses calendar, contacts, and notes.  I use AkrutoSync to sync these with my iPhone over home WiFi rather than going over the cloud.  My Outlook is the Windows 10 desktop app, not part of Office 365 or some other cloud repository.

For the calendar, I think that I've mostly created appointment/meeting events on Outlook, which then propagates to the phone over AkrutoSync.  This past week may have been my very first time creating an event on the phone and propagating it to Outlook.  It shows up in my calendar, but when I try to open it in Outlook, I get a popup window saying "Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item".

[image]

[image]

I tried repairing the PST file, creating a test event on the phone, and propagating it to Outlook; I got the same message.  I tried Windows's repair of Outlook, both quick and slow online repair, with the same result.

I was able to drag the un-openable calendar item to a folder, which showed as Test.msg, which is odd because "msg" is for email while calendar item extensions are "ics" or some other standard.  When I double-click the file, I get a message "Cannot read the item".  I sent the file to AkrutoSync, who said that they managed to open it in Outlook.

My Outlook is 2019, and bought as a standalone app (not part of Office 2019).  However, I also tried opening the file on another laptop with Office 2013, and I got the same message about the inability to open the file.  In contrast, AkrutoSync reported that they could open the file in both Outlook 2013 and 2019.  Therefore, it seemed unlikely that the file is malformed.  As confirmation, II also uploaded it to [encryptomatic email viewer](https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer) and [CoolUtils mail convert](https://www.coolutils.com/online/Mail-Converter); both sites parsed and displayed the content with no complaints.

It would seem that both of my specific versions of Outlook are alone in their inability to open the Test.msg file.  **What conditions (perhaps Windows settings, e.g., security, policy) prevent the opening of what is likely to be a validly formed `*.msg` file that contains a calendar item?**

*2022-05-23 update:* I was able to open Test.msg on a 3rd system with Outlook 2013 with no problems.  The only difference that I can think of between success on the 3rd system and failure on the 1st two systems is that Outlook had access to an Exchange server.  I doubt that many people would be familiar with how AkrutoSync propagates a calendar item from the iPhone to Outlook on the laptop.  In terms of less product-specific knowledge, however, **would anyone know whether an Outlook calendar item can be created in such a way as to presume the availability of an Exchange server and to rely on its functionality?**  That would explain my observations across the 3 systems.  The 1st 2 systems failed; each ran Outlook profiles containing only IMAP accounts in addition to a no-email account for the calendar. In contrast, the 3rd system succeeded; the Outlook profile had only a single Exchange account for both calendar and email.

*2022-05-24 update:* I asked someone using Outlook Desktop app as part of Office 365 to try opening Test.msg. It also fails. So that's one success out of 4 very different systems.  The outstanding distinguishing feature of that one success (of which I am aware) is that the Outlook profile consists of an Exchange account.

*2022-05-30 udpate:* AkrutoSync confirmed that in their successful tests, the Outlook profile had only an IMAP account (no Exchange account).  So the presence of an Exchange account in one of my Outlook profiles does *not* explain the success in opening the Test.msg container a calendar item.  It must be some other condition that allows Outlook to open the file in some situations.

P.S. I don't have a personal Office 365 or Outlook.com account and want to avoid creating one.  However, I did try opening the Test.msg as an email attachment by accessing my Gmail using the webmail interface.  It turns out that doesn't even store the file as a single file Test.msg.  It stores it as two attachments: "Test" and "noname" (no extension), where `Test` is much smaller than Test.msg and `noname` is much larger.  Gmail said that it doesn't have an app associated with the files.

Comment: Why would *some* Outlook installations not open correctly formed "msg" file?    --- in many many years I have only seen this if the message was damaged. I think with Office 365 there are Outlook message repair switches. Failing that, Stellar tools can repair a damaged email file.

Comment: @John: If the "msg" file were damaged, would the same version of Outlook open the file on one computer but not another?  Since AkrutoSync used the same versions of Outlook, that strongly suggests the problem is with my installations of Outlook 2013 and 2019.  Or rather, since I repaired my Outlook, maybe a Windows/Security/Policy setting.  Furthermore, the two online email parsers opened the file.  I'm not saying that you're wrong (truthfully, the anatomy of an email file is not my expertise), but I was wondering how much the above considerations weighed into the view that you shared?

Comment: Try using SCANPST .  Office Repair did not fix it so there is possibly an error that does not stop all Outlook Systems  SCANPST is a reliable tool

Comment: I was repeatedly using SCANPST until there were no more errors, and I maintained this practice throughout my troubleshooting efforts.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would *some* Outlook installations not open correctly formed "msg" file?  ...I tried repairing the PST file, creating a test event on the phone, and propagating it to Outlook;

PST is a proprietary DB, with `SCANPST` being used to fix and re-index it:

```bsh
# Root section of Outlook:
  %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\SCANPST.exe
```

- [Outlook Repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253):

  > You can use the Inbox Repair tool [`SCANPST.EXE`] to diagnose and repair errors in your Outlook data file [`.PST` or `.OST`]. The Inbox Repair tool checks the Outlook data files on your computer to see if they're in good shape.
  >
  > You might want to use the Inbox Repair tool in the following situations:
  >
  > - You receive a message that Outlook can't open your data file
  > - You receive a message that Outlook can't open the set of folders
  > - You think your Outlook data file may be damaged

1. **Try repairing the `.pst` with `SCANPST`:** 
    Make a backup copy of your PST file → Run `SCANPST` → Navigate to the `.pst` → Start 
    <sup>*(I have repaired PST files with `SCANPST`)*</sup>
2. **If that does not work, consider [Stellar Tools](https://www.stellarinfo.com/outlook-pst-file-recovery.php?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqpLJhd3x9wIVht7ICh2Ehw-jEAAYASAAEgIAV_D_BwE)** *(a professional repair tool)*

Comment: Repairing the PST file and repairing Outlook are part of what I described in my posted question.  Furthermore, Outlook had trouble opening the Test.msg file even when it was a separate file.  At least, my installations of Outlook did, on two separate computers.  AkrutoSync's did not, and two online mail viewers opened the Test.msg file without complaints.  That's why I wondered whether it might be a condition that is specific to my laptops, e.g., a Windows, security, or policy setting.

Comment: I would consider running it again. PST is proprietary and SCANPST fixes and re-indexes the file. Stellar tools would be the next step

Comment: I ran SCANPST repeatedly as I was troubleshooting. Each single run, as I call it, consists of iteratively running the app until there were no more errors. As I said, it's not the PST file, since the same problem is encountered when opening a single Test.msg, on two different laptops with two different versions of Outlook. The same two versions that AkrutoSync successfully used on the same file. Furthermore, the two email viewing sites that I mentioned had no problem. I'll keep Stellar Tools in mind, but the circusmtances point a local system conditions rather than a malformed Test.msg file.

Comment: Let us know. I do not think in 20 years of Outlook, I have seen a good Outlook install (you said you were sure Outlook was good) fail to read a good PST file.

Comment: I see what you're saying, John.  My suspicion that it is a local condition other than the PST file is based on other observations.  The same  problem afflicts the separate Test.msg file on *two* of my laptops.  However, circumstances indicate that the Test.msg file is good.  AkrutoSync can open it using the same versions of Outlook as me, and two email reading sites are able to open the Test.msg.  As well, the original Outlook 2019 was subject to both slow repair and lengthy repair with online assistance (those are the two options available when repairing Outlook 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that I'm not familiar with AkrutoSync, I want to confirm if the synced  calendar appear as files in outlook calendar? Could you share the screenshot for us for further troubleshooting?

And you have said that the calendar has been synced to outlook, could you open the calendar in web outlook?

To determine if the issue is related with windows side, you may need to test in another PC which is outside your organization to check if this issue continues.

Comment: Thanks, Joy. I added the images to the originally posted question. The calendar item shows up in Outlook's calendar. As I mentioned, I do not have a cloud account with Microsoft and I want to avoid creating one in order to minimize my footprint across the various clouds. My original question already described this problem on 2 Windows 10 systems; they are out-of-the-box ASUS and HP laptop OS images, not corporate images. Their Outlook versions were 2019 and 2013 respectively.

Comment: I tried a 3rd machine (corporate image + Outlook 2013). It *did* open Test.msg. The Outlook profile had only an Exchange account; in contrast, the 1st two had only IMAP accounts and a no-email account for the calendar. The problem is not about AkrutoSync, but a Test.msg that can be open by *some* Outlook installs/accounts and not others. Based on the other tests I desribed, the Test.msg containing the calendar item is correctly formed. Is it possible for such a file to presume the presence of an Exchange server and to rely on its functionality? That would explain what I see.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, exchange account will sync mail and calendar automatically from your phone to your outlook via activesync, there is no need 3rd tool to sync calendar, but imap account only sync mails not calendar, I believe it is the reason why exchange account can view calendar successfully. For more details: https://www.envisionup.com/blog/pop3-imap-microsoft-exchange-email-platform-use/

Comment: Thanks for that additional info, Joy. On the 1 system that could open Test.msg, it was just the usual ethernet network between the computer and the server (no phone involved). The phone syncing was simply the background that led to the question of *whether a well formed Test.msg containing a calendar item can be constructed in such a way as to require an Exchange server to open it.* After the troubleshooting described in my posted question, this is the focus rather than syncing of any sort. None of the systems described (now 4 systems) was syncing Test.msg with either a phone or a server.